# Which GNOME themes are suitable for black and white printing?

Tags: gnome, printing, theme, screenshot

I need to place some screenshots of GNOME applications, such as the file manager, in a book. The book will be printed in black and white, and, although shades of gray are okay, it is best that I avoid printing large areas of solid ink. Are there any GNOME themes which look good printed in black and white? What theme to many books use?

Comment: [`gtk-vector-screenshot`](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/projects#gtk-vector-screenshot) could be useful here.  Maybe you also could, without too much hassle, change the colors in the resulting SVG.